# $f(z)=2 \sin(\sqrt z)$, how to find $f'(\frac i2\pi^2)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

$f(z)=2 \sin(\sqrt z)$ and I want to find $f'(\frac i2\pi^2)$.

We can take $\sqrt z$ be principal value of function $z^\frac1 2$.

Should I start by considering $\sqrt z = e^{\frac12 \text{Log} (z)}$ and substitute it into my function then differentiate it or should I start with finding derivative of $f(z)$ using chain rule and substitution where I get $f'(z)= {\cos(\sqrt z)\over\sqrt z}$.

When is the part that I can start assuming $\sqrt z$ be principal value of function $z^\frac1 2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(z)=2\sin{(\sqrt z)}$$
$$f'(z)=2\cos{(\sqrt{z})}\times\frac{1}{2\sqrt{z}}=\frac{\cos{(\sqrt{z})}}{\sqrt{z}}$$
$$f'(\frac{i\pi^2}{2})=\frac{\cos{\sqrt{i\pi^2/2}}}{\sqrt{i\pi^2/2}}$$
Now we have
$$\frac{i\pi^2}{2}=\frac{\pi^2}{2}\exp{(\frac{i\pi}{2})}$$
$$\therefore \sqrt{\frac{i\pi^2}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi^2}{2}\exp{(\frac{i\pi}{2})}}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\exp{(\frac{i\pi}{4})}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\Big)=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{i\pi}{2}$$
$$\Big[\exp{(\frac{i\pi}{4})}=\cos{(\frac{\pi}{4})}+i\sin{(\frac{\pi}{4})}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\Big]$$
Giving the answer as
$$f'(\frac{i\pi^2}{2})=\frac{\cos{(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{i\pi}{2})}}{\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{i\pi}{2}}=\frac{2(\cos{(\pi/2)}\cos{(i\pi/2)}-\sin{(\pi/2)}\sin{(i\pi/2)})}{\pi(1+i)}$$
$$=\frac{-2i\sinh{(\pi/2)}}{\pi(1+i)}=\frac{e^{-\pi/2}-e^{\pi/2}}{2\pi}(1+i)$$

Answer (score 0):

Your derivation of $f'(z)$ is fine with either branch of $\sqrt z$. You have to use the principal branch only at the very end when you calculate the value of $\frac {\cos(\sqrt z)} {\sqrt z}$. The numerator is independent of the branch but $\sqrt {i\frac {\pi^{2}} 2}$ depends on the branch.